# devise user update form - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I basically want to get a custom form for updating my user profiles because I want a new view to update my user profiles.

This is the form I currently have with the error included.

```
    <%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource_name),
                     html: {method: :put, multipart: true} do |f| %>
        <label>Name</label>
          <%= f.label :name, value: 'ben'%>
          <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: false, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Stephen" %>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" value="<%= @user.name %>">
 <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-success ml-auto' %>
    <% end %>
```

In my routes I have  get '/user/:id', :to => 'user#profile', :as => :user

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a moment, read your error message, and think about it. The `form_for` helper is complaining that you're not passing it an argument when it needs one. What does the form_for helper do? It builds the HTML for a web form, and wires it up to some object that you specify. Common sense says it needs something to build a form for, so if you don't give it anything it throws the error you see.

Devise is designed so that you can use it with any model, not just `User`. It does this by referring to your model with a helper called `resource`, which is accessible from the devise controller & views, not the ones you created yourself. When you copy-pasted the devise form to a new view, you didn't define `resource` in the controller, so the form_for helper sees it as nil.

You need to pass whichever user you're working with from the controller to the view. You don't have to call it resource; the devise form is written for a much more general case than you are working with. Something like:

`<%= form_for @user do %>`

And define `@user` in the controller action.